# MySQL creating foreign key error 150

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Here is my sql script that I want to use to setup a database. Basically I've got people who are making choices, like a test/survey. I have some information about each person (person table) and their answers for each question (question table). Each person will answer multiple questions (so the primary key for the questions table is `(id, qid)`.

Here's my problem. I want to store an array of integers associated with each question. So I've created a third table, array, whose primary key is `(id, qid, idx)`, where idx is the index of the value in the array. Both the id and qid should be have a corresponding entry in the questions table, so I've made these foreign keys, but I get the common 150 errno when i do this. And I'm not sure why.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  age INT,
  income INT
);

CREATE TABLE questions (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  qid INT NOT NULL,
  a INT,
  b INT,
  c INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, qid),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES person(id)
);

CREATE TABLE array (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  qid INT NOT NULL,
  idx INT NOT NULL,
  array_value INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, qid, idx),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES person(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (qid) REFERENCES questions(qid)
);
```

This script does not work. If you remove the very last line which tried to set up a foreign key for qid, the script will run without error.

What is the error I'm making in trying to create this foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is to change that foreign key constraint reference the PRIMARY KEY of the `questions`  table.  Since the PRIMARY KEY is defined as the combination of two columns, the foreign key will need to be the same:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id,qid) REFERENCES questions(id,qid)
```

---

With the syntax you have, the error is because the `questions` table does not have an index with `qid` as the leading index. If you added such an an index on `questions`, then you could create a foreign key that references the column `qid`.  The InnoDB allows a non-unique key to be referenced by a foreign key, but... you don't want to do that. That's a non-standard extension. And the documentation warns against it.

The normal pattern is to have the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) as the target of a foreign key, which is what the foreign key definition (above) does.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Your model looks fine.

But my personal preference would be to have a single column as the PRIMARY KEY of the `question` table. (I also name all tables in the singular, to match what the developers are going to name their  Class.)

```
person
  id (PK)

question
  id (PK)
  person_id (FK references person.id)
```

I wouldn't name that third table "array", I'd give it a different name. I'd name it as what "one" of those integer values represents, but it's not clear to me what those integer values really are.

```
score
  id (PK)
  question_id (FK references question.id)
  idx
  score_value
```

That model just suits my personal preferences. What you have is certainly workable.

Comment: Thanks, that works and was what I was going for. Your answer gives me the impression that what I'm doing is not the proper way to handle my situation. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? (That is, associate an array with every record in a table.)

Comment: What you have looks okay to me; my personal preference would be to have a single column as the PRIMARY KEY of the questions table; but that's informed by the developers that want a consistent pattern for their DAOs, wanting a single value, native datatype; not wanting the additional complexity of an Object (Class) with two members, as the identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Column `qid` in table `questions` has no guaranteed uniqueness. This is a requirement of the target key 
of a foreign key. So, target is either a Primary key or has a Unique constraint.

Did you perhaps mean:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id, qid) REFERENCES person(id, qid)
```

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. In that case, what would be the standard way of handling as case like my current one? Introducing an arrayid field in questions, that would be unique, and having the array table reference that arrayid instead of qid?